# Graph Theory question about proving isomorphism without using adjacency matrices

Tags: graph-theory

Read this question

[image]

How do you prove something like this, the only way I can think of at the moment is to write up a complete adjacency matrix and have a program test all permutations to see if there's a match..

Comment: I think it should be sufficient to draw an arrow between each corresponding pair of vertices.  On the other hand proving that two graphs are _not_ isomorphic may require brute force.

Comment: could you explain a little more please, thank you

Comment: To prove two graphs are isomorphic you need to provide the isomorphism (either explicitly or implicitly). To prove two graphs are _not_ isomophic, you need to find a distinguishing feature, one that cannot be mapped by any isomorphism, e.g., a vertex of unique degree. For example, in your case you could consider the number of cycles of length 4 (if I didn't make any mistake the middle graph has only 4 such cycles).

Comment: Yes, thank you for the confirmation, I did notice that and crossed out the middle graph from being isomorphic to the other 2.

Comment: i was able to show the first and last graph are isomorphic thank you for your help guys, have a good night

Comment: @dtldarek, you should expand a little on your comment and post it as an answer (so that this doesn't go on the Unanswered Questions queue).

Comment: @MikePierce I didn't suspect the OP would be satisfied with such a short note, but it seems it did the job. Thanks for pinging me, converted it into an answer already.

Answer (score 4):

It seems my comment answered the question, so here it is as an answer:

To prove two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic you need to provide the isomorphism (either explicitly or implicitly), that is, a bijective function $\phi : V(G_1) \to V(G_2)$ such that

$$(v_1,v_2) \in E(G_1) \iff \big(\phi(v_1),\phi(v_2)\big) \in E(G_2).$$

To prove two graphs are not isomophic, you need to show that it is impossible to find such a bijective function.
One approach is to find a distinguishing feature, 
one that cannot be mapped by any isomorphism, 
for example, a vertex of unique degree.
In your case you could consider the number of cycles of length $4$, if the graphs are isomorphic, they have to contain the same number of cycles for any given length (if I didn't make any mistake the middle graph has only $4$ such cycles).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$